# What does this Windows bat command mean?

Tags: maven, batch-file

I read the following command from the batch file to run Maven on Windows `mvn.bat`:

```
if not "_%M2_HOME:~-1%"=="_\" goto checkMBat
```

And

```
if "%@eval[2+2]" == "4" goto 4NTArgs
```

What does this batch script mean?

### ADD 1

As I tried, it seems `_%M2_HOME:~-1%` returns the `_` plus the last 1 letter of the environment variable `"_%M2_HOME%`. But what's the name of this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%VAR:~-1%` gets the last character in the envvar. The first snippet verifies that the envvar M2_HOME doesn't end with `\`. Note: [Maven's docs](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) say,

> Note: For Maven 2.0.9, also be sure that the M2_HOME doesn't have a '\' as last character.

This might be related. They probably want to prepend M2_HOME to subdir names and always include a dirsep. The variable substitution in "_%...%" is unaffected by the initial underscore. Experessing it that way just ensures that the underscore is at the beginning of the output. I can't say for certain, but it may have been expressed that way to avoid a backslashed quote, e.g. `"\"`.

The second is not any CMD/batch that I'm familiar with. The comment (assuming this comes from mvn.bat) says "4NT shell", which I take to mean that this batch file could be run in the [Take Command Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_Command_Console) which probably has extensions to MS CMD features. For example, `%@eval[...]` probably does [numeric evaluation in 4NT](https://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?f_eval.htm). This would effectively be a check to see if the script were running in a 4NT shell.

Answer (score 2):

The first one takes the last character of `%M2_HOME%`, adds an underscore to the front, and checks to see if the resulting string is `_\` - in short, it checks that the last character of %M2_HOME% is a backslash by using [substrings](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MidString).

The second one is how you determine if 4NT is installed on your computer; if it is, [there will be a variable function called @eval](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2685).

Comment: Thanks! What does the single `%` mean in the `%@eval`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with 4NT at all, but it's either simply part of the variable call, or it's a typo that somehow still works and should actually be `if "%@eval[2+2]%"=="4"`

Answer (score 0):

I found the explanation to `"_%M2_HOME:~-1%"` below link. It's a variable substring operation.

http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html